# Domain of integration and area.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y^2}^{\frac{y^2+3}{4}}f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{0}^{\frac{3}{4}}\int_{-x}^0 f(x,y)dydx+\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^1\int_{-x}^{\sqrt{4x-3}}f(x,y)dydx$$

So i made this graph to find the domain of $I$. (Yellow is the first, blue is the second and red is the third)
[image]

So if i want to find the area of the three combined i use thhese two integrals:

$$\int_{0}^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{x}}f(x,y)dydx+\int_{0}^1 \int_{-x}^0 f(x,y)dydx=\frac{7}{6}$$

But the answer the proffesor gave was $\frac{5}{6}$. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: May we know $f(x,y)$?

Comment: It's not necessary since is the area so f(x,y)=1

Comment: @EmmaWool Your professor calculated the areas between $x=y^2$ and $4x-3=y^2$ which doesn't contain the $\color{red}{red}$ area.

Answer (score 0):

No, you did right. The total sum of the three integrals is also $\frac{7}{6}:$

$$I=\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{9}{32}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{32}\right]=\frac{7}{6}.$$